# Scroll to get all the links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are 3821 links but they gave me only 103 links I also apply the condition of `window.scroll` to the links get all but they do not work

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import time
    import ssl
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    
    # ... Rest of your code ...
    
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("http://www.servicealberta.gov.ab.ca/find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm")
    
    # Click the button to load initial content
    click_on_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td:nth-child(1) input:nth-child(1)")
    click_on_button.click()
    
    
    time.sleep(2)
    
    base_url = "http://www.servicealberta.gov.ab.ca/"
    
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        
    data = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    links = data.select("tbody td[colspan='4'] a")
    for link in links:
        url = base_url + link['href']
        print(url)
    print(len(url))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all links from the page in `pandas` DataFrame you can use this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "http://www.servicealberta.gov.ab.ca/find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm"
payload = {"faction": "SearchResults", "BusName": "", "BusType": "all", "BusMunc": ""}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(api_url, data=payload).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('td[colspan="4"]:has(a)'):
    link = row.a["href"]
    name = row.a.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    type_ = row.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
    area = row.find_next("td").find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)

    all_data.append({"name": name, "type": type_, "area": area, "link": link})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.tail())
```

Prints:

```
                                                                   name                type      area                                                                 link
3816                       ZOUPPAS BARRY SCOTT d.b.a ARDCO CONSTRUCTION  Prepaid Contractor   AIRDRIE  /find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm?faction=SearchDetails&BusID=25581
3817  ZSA LEGAL RECRUITMENT LIMITED d.b.a ZSA LEGAL RECRUITMENT LIMITED   Employment Agency   CALGARY   /find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm?faction=SearchDetails&BusID=9367
3818                                  ZU HOUSE LTD. d.b.a ZU HOUSE LTD.  Prepaid Contractor  EDMONTON  /find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm?faction=SearchDetails&BusID=43181
3819        ZYIA ACTIVE CANADA LIMITED d.b.a ZYIA ACTIVE CANADA LIMITED       Direct Seller  EDMONTON  /find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm?faction=SearchDetails&BusID=44542
3820                    ZZ CONSTRUCTION LTD. d.b.a ZZ CONSTRUCTION LTD.  Prepaid Contractor   CALGARY  /find-if-business-is-licenced.cfm?faction=SearchDetails&BusID=33207
```